# Renaming duplicates with any vacant value within a certain interval

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

The values of my column of interest (col1) should range from 0-999. I'm looking for a way to assign one of each duplicate a new value that lies within my this range 0-999.

Only features that are identical in both col1 and col2 are considered duplicates. Is there a way to identify "vacant" numbers and assign those to duplicated values.

At this point I use this code to identify duplicates and set new values for both of them:

```
UPDATE table AS t1 
  SET col1 = t1.id || t1.col1
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table AS t2
    WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
      AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
      AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
  )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the GIS component to your question? Duplicate geometries?

Comment: yes, that would be it

Comment: The answer is the same without a geometry column.

Comment: You will need to write a recursive CTE query to do this. However, what happens if you have more than 999 unique combinations of col1 and col2.

Comment: can't you just create a sequence and call it for a value? you can set a max value for it, too.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. That is far too sensible an answer. I thought the vagueness of the question merited a more random and complex response, such as use a recursive CTE. It is possible that your suggestion would work, but impossible to know from the information so far provided :D

Comment: not sure if I get this right, but you could even `DENSE_RANK()` with `PARTITION BY` the duplicate condition.

Comment: You could do something along those lines, but I am not sure how you would keep it in the range 0-999.

Comment: @JohnPowell :-) yeah that was adding some mystery and complexity back in. but it would be ridiculous to stop at 999 if there were more than 1k duplicates...

Comment: Well, the vagueness of question comes from me not being sure of how/If this is possible. To keep it under 999 is not necesaery in my opinion but If possible it woud be nice. I Will look in to all of your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone would run into something similair: I solved this by using the following statements. However,  I'm aware this may not be the most effective way. For example I was struggling not to create new tables all the time. Parts of this should be run over and over, until all values are unique in my columns of interest.

```
-- Returns table with rank based on number of duplicates in my chosen columns : col_1 and col_2.   
    CREATE TABLE table1 as 
    SELECT *,
     DENSE_RANK () OVER (
     PARTITION BY table.col_1, table.col_2
     ORDER BY table.id 
     ) AS "ranking"
    FROM
     table

    -- Adds up value from ranking and from col_1 to a new column but leaves hte unique rows.      
    Create table table2 as (SELECT *, COALESCE(col_1,0) + COALESCE(ranking,0) as col_3
    FROM <table2> 
    WHERE ranking > 1);

    -- New column to table1  to be able to union the two tables.
    ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD COLUMN col_3 bigint;

     -- Union of both tables to get a common col3 in table3.  
    Create table table3
    as 
    select * from table2
    union all
    select * from table1 where ranking = 1;


    -- Adds the old values from col_1 to col_3 where the value is null (and the ranking = 1).

    UPDATE table3 AS t1 
      SET col_3 = t2.col_1 
      FROM table3 AS t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id
          AND t1.col_2 Is null;
```